# Message Prioritization with Spring-XD

Tags: spring-xd

We are on version 1.3.1 using RabbitMQ 3.5.7 as the message bus.

For a stream receiving messages via an input queue I want to be able to set message priority. I have confirmed that I can do so via the amqp template and the MessagePostProcessor. That is when I examine the queue (with no consumer) I see the priority header properly set. However, when I deploy the stream (with only one consumer) it is consuming in the order the messages where received. Based on my reading the message of priority of 7 should be consumed before a message with priority 5 for example - I hope that is correct?

My question is do I need to do anything on the spring-xd setup side to enable message prioritization?

Thanks,
Mark

Hi Gary - I think the message bus is good. The issue is on the producer I am creating via:

```
<rabbit:queue name="foo">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-max-priority" value="10"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

This queue is being create/instantiated on a  spring-batch job we. I looked in the error logs for rabbitmq: It had this message:

> =ERROR REPORT==== 13-Apr-2016::11:01:35 === Channel error on
>   connection <0.15708.1> (127.0.0.1:40887 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/',
>   user: 'guest'), channel 1: {amqp_error,precondition_failed,
>               "inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'xdbus.queue:CPSFileCopyWorker_ws0' in vhost '/': received '10' but
>   current is '10'",
>               'queue.declare'}

This seems to allow the queue definition to for an already created queue we the priority arg set:

```
<rabbit:queue name="foo" auto-declare="false">
    <rabbit:queue-arguments>
        <entry key="x-max-priority" value="10"/>
    </rabbit:queue-arguments>
</rabbit:queue>
```

Comment: I think I found a way around my issue - I had to add the auto-declare=false attribute on the queue definition

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean a stream `rabbit | ...` rather than talking about the internal queues used by XD when using a rabbit transport.

If so, there is nothing special needed on the XD side, but you have to [configure the queue to support priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html).

**EDIT**

Here's the code from the Message Bus...

```
private void declareQueueIfNotPresent(Queue queue) {
    if (this.rabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(queue.getName()) == null) {
        this.rabbitAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Gary - yes for rabbit_input_queue > .... thanks I will checkout those instructions.

Comment: looks like this should get me there: <rabbit:queue name="${someQueueName}">
     <rabbit:queue-arguments>
            <entry key="x-max-priority" value="10"/>
      </rabbit:queue-arguments>
    </rabbit:queue>

Comment: Yes; looks correct; note that this requires RabbitMQ 3.5 or above and you can't change it if the queue already exists (the queue will have to be deleted first).

Comment: Thanks Gary - yes I just hit that issue. So I have a follow-on question: since the queue that I am using is being created by Spring-XD upon the creation of a Stream. I need to ask if there is a way to override these type of input queues to have that priority setting? currently we are not using the internal inter-module messaging with Rabbit as we are forcing the streams to have all their modules on the same container.

Comment: Here is an example Stream definition: stream create --name test --definition "queue:input_rabbit_queue > some-processor | some-sink" maybe this is an unsupported side effect that the queue gets created for us via this type of definition?

Comment: That's why I asked if it was the rabbit source you are using or an internal XD queue (`rabbit | ...` Vs. a named channel `queue:foo > ...`). If the queue exists already XD will not declare it (we addd that code to support custom arguments). You can manually create the queue with the argument before you deploy the streams. Or, switch to the rabbit sink on the sending side `... | rabbit` and a rabbit source on the receiving side `rabbit | ...`. That way, you completely control the rabbit infrastructure between the 2 streams. There is no way to provide additional arguments for XD-created queues.

Comment: Hi Gary - sorry to beat a dead horse here - but after externally setting up the queue with the x-max-priority : 10. I am getting the following error : Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-max-priority' for queue 'xdbus.queue:CPSFileCopyWorker_ws0' in vhost '/': received '10' but current is '10', class-id=50, method-id=10)  I used the above context to reference the queue I want to send the message

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me - see the edit in my answer - we don't even attempt to declare the queue if it already exists. I just tested with `xd:>stream create foo --definition "queue:foo > log" --deploy` and `xd:>stream create bar --definition "time > queue:foo" --deploy` having first created `xdbus.queue:foo` with an argument, and had no problems.